# How to do a Grid plot by condition - R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, graphics, grid

I have several files, sharing identical and different traits. So I made a looping based on the column names to do histogram:

Like this (just a part):

```
for (i in 3:10) {
if (colnames(data)[i]=="ww_age") {
  a<-ggplot(data, aes(x=ww_age)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")

}}
```

to

```
for (i in 3:10) {
if (colnames(data)[i]=="ww_weight") {
  f<-ggplot(data, aes(x=ww_weight)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")

}}
```

So, I will have several combinations for each file, for example, for file `A` I will have `a,b,c,d,e,f` graphics, and for file `B` I will have `a,c,d`. So, I would like to do a grid for each set of graphics, Like this:

```
pdf("figura3.pdf",width=8,height=14,paper='special')
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(a), ggplotGrob(b),ggplotGrob(c), 
                ggplotGrob(d), ggplotGrob(e),ggplotGrob(f), 
size = "last"))
dev.off()
```

But how can I do by condition? For `a` to `f` in situation A and just using `a,c,d` in the situation B.

Comment: you don't need to iterate. Do you mind providing a table with for file A, what are the columns you need and for file B, what you need etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example we have two files,

```
df = data.frame(x=1,y=2,sapply(1:8,function(i)rnorm(100,i,1)))
colnames(df)[3:10] = paste0("column_",letters[1:8])
write.table(df,"fileA.txt",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep="\t")

df = data.frame(x=1,y=2,sapply(1:8,function(i)rnorm(100,i,1)))
colnames(df)[3:10] = paste0("column_",LETTERS[1:8])
write.table(df,"fileB.txt",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

Now we write a function that can read in a file, take the defined columns and make the combined plot:

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

plotfun = function(datafile,colvars){
data = read.delim(datafile,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
plotdf = pivot_longer(data[,colvars],everything())
p = ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=value))+
geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white") + facet_wrap(~name)
return(p)
}
```

We test it on one file, with some columns:

```
plotfun("fileA.txt",c("column_a","column_b","column_e"))
```

[image]

Now we need to define a list that says what are the files, what is the column to plot and what to save it as:

```
LIST = list(
A = list(file="fileA.txt",
colvars = c("column_a","column_b","column_c","column_d","column_e","column_f"),
pdf = "A.png"),
B = list(file="fileA.txt",colvars = c("column_a","column_c","column_d"),pdf="B.png")
)
```

Now we iterate through this list:

```
for(i in 1:length(LIST)){
p = plotfun(LIST[[i]]$file,LIST[[i]]$colvars)
ggsave(p,file=LIST[[i]]$pdf)
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Iterate didn't work this message appears:
 `for(i in 1:length(LIST)) {p = plotfun(LIST\[\[i\]\]$file,LIST\[\[i\]\]$colvars)
Error: unexpected input in "for(i in 1:length(LIST)) {p = plotfun(LIST\"
ggsave(p,file=LIST\[\[i\]\]$pdf)}
Error: unexpected input in "  ggsave(p,file=LIST\"`